# Container content is not being copied to docker host using docker volume

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I'm running python script inside container which is generating output.txt file. I want to run this python script just once in container and output.txt should be available in my Docker host, but running below docker volume commands file is not being copied.

My Dockerfile

```
[root@server test]# cat Dockerfile
FROM centos
RUN yum install -y https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
RUN yum install -y python36u python36u-libs python36u-devel python36u-pip
RUN ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python
RUN mkdir /app
COPY 16-reading_and_writing_file.py /app
RUN python --version
CMD ["python", "/app/16-reading_and_writing_file.py"]
```

My python script

```
target3 = open("output.txt",'w')
line1 = "Hello"
line2 = "How Are You"
target3.write(line1)
target3.write("\n")
target3.write(line2)
target3.write("\n")
target3.close()
print ("Hello")
```

docker run command

```
[root@server test]# docker run -it -v /jaydeep/docker_practice/test/:/app jaydeepuniverse/jira
Hello
[root@server test]#
```

I need to have output.txt here in docker volume path given in command

```
[root@server test]# pwd
/jaydeep/docker_practice/test
[root@server test]# ls -ltrh
total 8.0K
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 183 May 17 08:25 16-reading_and_writing_file.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 510 May 17 23:35 Dockerfile
[root@server test]#
```

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are running `CMD ["python", "/app/16-reading_and_writing_file.py"]`, Your current working directory is `/`.

So `output.txt` file be created under `/` not in `/app`

So it's better to use `WORKDIR` in your `Dockerfile` to mention your working directory

```
FROM centos
RUN yum install -y https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
RUN yum install -y python36u python36u-libs python36u-devel python36u-pip
RUN ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY 16-reading_and_writing_file.py .
RUN python --version
CMD ["python", "16-reading_and_writing_file.py"]
```

Now the file will be created under `/app`

**OR**

In your python code, you can use the **os** module to form the path

```
import os

output_file_path  = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), 'output.txt')
target3 = open(output_file_path,'w')
line1 = "Hello"
line2 = "How Are You"
target3.write(line1)
target3.write("\n")
target3.write(line2)
target3.write("\n")
target3.close()
print ("Hello")
```

This will help you create your `output.txt` in the same directory where **16-reading_and_writing_file.py** is present, no matter wherever you are.

Comment: Thanks much, actually I had included workdir initially but deleted then considering running python command as /app/scriptName.py and thought output.txt would created there only. Thanks again.